# OpenRemoteBaseKey UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation

Tags: c#, wpf, task

I want to access the RegistryKeys of a remote PC in my network, if there is no terminalNumber passed as a parameter.

```
    public LoginEntity(string ipAdress, string username, string password, string terminalNumber = "")
    {
        this.IpAdress = ipAdress;
        this.Username = username;
        this.Password = password;

        if (terminalNumber == "")
        {
            try
            {
                RegistryKey rKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, IpAdress, RegistryView.Registry64);
                rKey = rKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Test", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
                var key = rKey.GetValue("terminalNumber", "NOTFOUND");

                if (key is string)
                {
                    if ((string)key != "NOTFOUND")
                        this.TerminalNumber = (string)key;
                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("UnauthorizedException: Calling TerminalNumber from Remote Registry Keys");
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("IOException: Remote PC not available");
            }
        }
        else
            this.TerminalNumber = terminalNumber;
    }
```

Due to safety reasons the Subkey in this example is called 'Test'.

But at
`RegistryKey rKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, IpAdress, RegistryView.Registry64);`
the application throws an **UnauthorizedAccessException**.

What I did:

- I already run Visual Studio 2019 as an administator.
- The LoginEntity was instantiated in a Task*. (As I am using WPF, I don't want my UI to freeze, so I run it in a Task).

*The Task call is located in the MainWindow()-Constructor of my WPF-Application

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
     List<LoginEntity> loginUser = Utility.ReadLoginDataFromCsv(loginUserPath);
     this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
     {
          Listview.ItemsSource = loginUser;
          lblUserLoading.Content = "";
      });
});
```

```
public static List<LoginEntity> ReadLoginDataFromCsv(string path, bool ignoreFirstLine = false)
{
     List<LoginEntity> list = new List<LoginEntity>();
     var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.UTF8);

     if (ignoreFirstLine)
          lines = lines
               .Skip(1)
               .ToArray();

     foreach (string line in lines)
     {
          var rowData = line.Split(';');
          LoginEntity le = new LoginEntity(rowData[0], rowData[1], rowData[2], rowData[3]);
          if (le.IpAdress != "" && le.Username != "" && le.Password != "")
               list.Add(le);
     }

     return list;
}
```

Does anyone know why I get the UnAuthorizedException and how I can get rid of it?

Comment: Just a note, instead of calling Dispatcher.Invoke from a Task action, better do something like `Listview.ItemsSource = await Task.Run(() => Utility.ReadLoginDataFromCsv(loginUserPath)); lblUserLoading.Content = "";`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Clemens. But I think my code was a bit unclear. I run this Task in the MainWindow()-Constructor of  my WPF-Application. So I would not be able to call my function in the way that you suggested.

Comment: Still any awaitable call should be awaited. So you should move it to an async Loaded event handler.

Comment: As another note, if you move to .Net Core, you could make ReadLoginDataFromCsv async by using File.ReadAllLinesAsync. You wouln'd have to use Task.Run at all. Besides that it's unclear whether all this is necessary at all. There are certainly not thousands of LoginEntities to be read from file.

Comment: I understand that it is not necessary to implement, but if I want to access a remote RegistryKey, and the remote PC is currently not available (for example it is shut down), then it would take around 20 seconds for RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey() to understand that the remote PC is not available. And if I want to check 10 remote RegistryKeys outside of a task, it would take a couple minutes to start the UI. So I want to call it in a task to reduce the time to start the UI.

Comment: Moving to .Net Core would surely make my work a bit easier, but I don't think that you can create a WPF App (.NET Core), but only WPF App (.NET Framework). Atleast that is what VS 2019 v16.2.5 tells me.

Comment: Well, you can of course create a .NET Core WPF App. Not sure since which VS 2019 version exactly, though. Just upgrade to the latest.